# git clone fails with "packfile cannot be accessed"

Tags: git, kernel

I'm trying to clone the kernel, but `git clone` fails with this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Counting objects: 5394786, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6010/6010), done.
remote: fatal: packfile ./objects/pack/pack-739267fbbad35d713a4648c227cd63f8a926bd0d.pack cannot be accessed
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried googling it but none of the suggested solutions solved it for me. Any ideas?

Comment: There was an issue with libgit2 unpacking very large pack files (2G) when used on 32bit systems (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/534) that may be related.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and i got the data on my system.

Check your .gitconfig , there could be some unnecessary mal-function . Or simply just reinstall the git , this will fix you problem.

Comment: Check what in .gitconfig? I just have a bunch of aliases and formatting settings in my .gitconfig.

Comment: Probably you could have [core] and [pack] menu . So if you have the memory limit like "packSizeLimit = 500m"  and "packedGitLimit = 500m". which will be less than the size of repo .